# Django: is_secure() decorator not working

Tags: django

I'm converting some FBVs with signals to CBVs, so I have this decorator:

```
def ensure_https(view_func):
    def _checkssl(request, *args, **kwargs):
        print request.is_secure()
        if not settings.DEBUG and not request.is_secure():
            url_str = request.build_absolute_uri()
            url_str = url_str.replace('http://', 'https://')
            return HttpResponseRedirect(url_str)
        return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
    return _checkssl
```

and added it to a function in a class based view, as so:

```
class ExampleTemplateView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'example.html'

    @ensure_https
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
        return HttpResponseRedirect(/hello/')
```

But I get the following error:

```
'ExampleTemplateView' object has no attribute 'is_secure'
```

However, when I use this decorator on a function-based view, it works just fine.  Should I be using a particular CBV?

If you need anymore code or info, please let me know.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have `signal` and `decorator` confused as the pattern in your code is a `decorator`. Depending on what you're doing there might be better alternatives to where you put the URL redirection logic. I'm thinking webserver(nginx), [`HTTP Strict Transport Security` HTTP header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Security/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) or [middleware](http://www.redrobotstudios.com/blog/2010/02/06/requiring-https-for-certain-paths-in-django/). Having said that, [from the django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-the-class):

> To decorate every instance of a class-based view, you need to decorate
>   the class definition itself. To do this you apply the decorator to the
>   dispatch() method of the class.
>
> A method on a class isn’t quite the same as a standalone function, so
>   you can’t just apply a function decorator to the method – you need to
>   transform it into a method decorator first. The method_decorator
>   decorator transforms a function decorator into a method decorator so
>   that it can be used on an instance method. For example:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

class ProtectedView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'secret.html'

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(ProtectedView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: You're quite right!  Decorator not signal.  Other things on my mind...Thanks!